# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed

Tags: 7, database, migrations

I got this problem with my drupal 7.24, Windows server 2012, IIS8 and the sql server 2012.

I'm using the last dev version of sqlsrv which is suppose to fix a similar bug, but I still have this one.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type `nvarchar` to `varbinary(max)` is not allowed. Use the `CONVERT` function to run this query. in `dblog_watchdog()` (line 160 of D:\inetpub\website\modules\dblog\dblog.module).

I've migrated my DB from a mysql to the sql server through the migration tool and using the drivers 5 and 3.51 to convert the schema. (got the same error in both case)
BTW I have hexadecimal data sometime instead of normal data.

```
function dblog_watchdog(array $log_entry) {
  Database::getConnection('default', 'default')->insert('watchdog')
    ->fields(array(
      'uid' => $log_entry['uid'],
      'type' => substr($log_entry['type'], 0, 64),
      'message' => $log_entry['message'],
      'variables' => serialize($log_entry['variables']),
      'severity' => $log_entry['severity'],
      'link' => substr($log_entry['link'], 0, 255),
      'location' => $log_entry['request_uri'],
      'referer' => $log_entry['referer'],
      'hostname' => substr($log_entry['ip'], 0, 128),
      'timestamp' => $log_entry['timestamp'],
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

On the dbo.watchdog I have a column call variables which is a varbinary(max) (used to be a LONGBLOB on mysql) and got hex data now. I think the problem is coming from here.
When I comment those lines (insert query), it works, but with a lot of warning like:

> Warning: `array_flip()`: Can only flip `STRING` and `INTEGER` values! in `DrupalDefaultEntityController->load()` (line 173 of D:\inetpub\website\includes\entity.inc).
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\inetpub\wendy\includes\common.inc:2700) in `drupal_send_headers()` (line 1216 of D:\inetpub\website\includes\bootstrap.inc)
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type `nvarchar` to `varbinary(max)` is not allowed. Use the `CONVERT` function to run this query. in `variable_set()` (line 975 of D:\inetpub\website\includes\bootstrap.inc).

Anyone got an idea how to fix that?

Comment: hello. This site is meant to be a repository of knowledge, so please refrain from using "last sql server" - unless you add a date. But version number, build number or release date would be more meaningful for people determining if they have the same issue, or only similar one.

Comment: ah sorry about that, that's the last sql server 2012

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. You only need to be sorry if you do things on purpose or refuse to listen ;) Thanks for updating. Will let you know if I'll have an idea (but hopefully you will draw attention of someone who knows already and will not need me ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the main problem, when I was using the SQL migration tool to migrate, it was creating a database, so I devided to create mine to check. The one created by the tool was Latin1_general_CL_AS and mine was SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS instead. That seems to have fixed the problem